# Python syslog - view syslog messages

Tags: python

I'm running the following code:
    # create logger
    logger = logging.getLogger("myApp")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

```
# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.debug('debug sample message')
```

Now, on a different python script, I'd like to read those messages (that belongs to "myApp", from syslog) - how can I do so???

Thanks a lot,
Efrat

Answer (score 0):

you can read as file :

```
important = []
keep_phrases = ["test",
                "important",
                "warning"]

with open("log.log" 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for phrase in keep_phrases:
            if phrase in line:
            important.append(line)
            print line
            break
print(important)
```